# Relay control with Raspberry Pi and Python3

Tags: python-3.x

below is a section of code I am using to control a relay to open electric gates via a relay which is controlled via pin 7 on a raspberry pi GPIO.  The gates only need a momentary voltage (via the relay contacts) to open.

My question is, what do I need to add to this code to make the relay only switch on for 0.5 Seconds when pin 7 goes high.  This would enable relay to return to the off state and then wait for the next time GPIO pin 7 goes high, the gates do not need any commands from the GPIO to close after a certain time, they close under the control of the separate gate control system.

```
if name=="gate":
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(int(7), GPIO.OUT)   ## Setup GPIO Pin to OUTPUT
GPIO.output(int(7), state) ## State is true/false
```

Many thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

In this example I will use `gpiozero` library instead of `RPi.GPIO` because I like the way, how this library handle events.

```
from gpiozero import Button, OutputDevice
from time import sleep
from signal import pause

buttonPin = 4
relayPin = 7

button = Button(buttonPin)
button.when_pressed = ButtonPressedCallback
relay = OutputDevice(relayPin)

def ButtonPressedCallback():
    relay.on()
    sleep(0.5)
    relay.off()

pause()
```

I hope, I understood your question good.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay, perhaps I should have provided more information.  The project uses Aleaxa to command the raspberry pi to "turn on" the gate,  This makes PIN 7 go high and switch on a relay, the relay then activates the open sequence of the gates.  However the Relay is left in the ON sate and as such the gates will now stay open>  What I am looking for is code i can add in to my program the will automatically turn off the relay after 30 seconds.  This will then allow the gate to automatically close.  Thanks Peter

Comment: above code works well, but in my case when I use while loop, relay never turns off unless I exit program. Even while loop simply prints random string and nothing else inside. any idea?

Comment: Jaydeep, can you provide example of your code?